# C++ sorting array of true false

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have been assigned two similar tasks which should be pretty easy but I need a clarification on what I can and can't do with c++.

Task 1:
Suppose you have an array of n elements containing only two distinct keys, true and false.  Give an O(n) algorithm to rearrange the list so that all false elements precede the true elements. You may use only constant extra space.

For task two I need to do the same thing but now there is an extra key "maybe".  So i need to sort the array so false precedes maybe and maybe precedes true in O(n).

I am deciding to use insertion sort on the first task and quick sort on the second.  My first question is whether or not it is ideal to create an array and sort it with values true false and/or maybe.  In my opinion I would want to fist change all the values of false, true and maybe to 0,1,2 and sort the array by numerical values in ascending order.  I would do this by first going through the array and changing the values then sorting after.  What would be the best way to change the values (if even needed).  Would this keep the algorithm in O(n) time?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Inertion sort is not O(n) everytime...

Comment: The O(n) requirement is incompatible with your decision to use insertion sort. You need to change the requirement. ;-)

Comment: For T/F: There are only two possible values. Iterate through once and count them. Iterate through a second time and set your ordering (do your sort).

Comment: What would be O(n)?  It seems like this is what my instructor was looking for when asking this question.

Comment: Still need to know if it is possible to compare True and False.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, just as with ints.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a classic sorting algorithm that runs in O(n) time called the [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort). More precisely, it runs in O(n+k) time and uses O(k) space, where `k` is the number of possible keys.

Here, you have only 3 possible keys, `true` `maybe`, and `false`, so `k=3`. Because this is a constant, it is eliminated in big-O notation, so you get O(n) running time and O(1) space.

Comment: It might be useful to include a brief description of counting sort in the answer itself. Related Meta discussion - [Is mentioning a well-known data structure or algorithm considered a link-only answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/212919)

Answer (score 2):

For 1.:
implement a kind-of counting sort: go through your table counting only 'false' elements. Then write a counted number of false elements to your array and fill the rest of the array with true values.

For 2.: same as for 1., but this time count both false and maybe. Then fill your array just like in 1.

Answer (score 2):

The question is phrased somewhat like homework, but in the real world, [`std::partition`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) is the right tool for the job.

There's also `stable_partition` which is slower but preserves ordering, and `partition_copy` which is O(N) and stable but takes extra space by making a copy.

For the second task, just call `partition` twice, once to separate `false` from `maybe` and `true`  and another time to separate `maybe` from `true`. The total cost is still O(N).

Comment: When the question asks for specific time and space requirements, I don't think just mentioning a standard function with no explanation as to how it works is useful as an answer. Not to mention that it isn't clear what the space complexity of this function is from the answer or the given link.

Comment: @Dukeling `std::partition` is O(N) or this wouldn't be an answer. However a much stronger complexity spec is given in the link, just scroll down to the "Complexity" heading. None of the standard algorithms take extra space unless otherwise noted.

Comment: @Dukeling he didn't "just mention" it, and it's also not clear from the answer or the given link that the function won't delete your home directory.

Comment: @jthill I guess we have different definitions of what "just mentioning" means. Either way, I don't see an explanation of how it works (or how it might be implemented) in the answer.

Comment: The way you're using `std::partition` here basically makes it a radix sort.

Comment: @nneonneo Yes, but critically, you don't have to write it yourself.

Comment: @Dukeling The link also has an example implementation. Anyway, the higher-voted answer is (at least) equally a lazy link as this. That one points at Wikipedia and mine points at cppreference, which is also a public wiki using the very same software.

Comment: @Dukeling yeah, I do apologize for being so curt, but really, can you think of any useful reason to quote or excerpt the Standard's description of such a fundamental operation?  For things like this, I'd say OP does need to be pointed at TFM.  And if the operation of `partition` is unclear from its performance characterization in terms of counting swaps, I really think no amount of help could suffice.

Comment: @jthill @ Potatoswatter It's about being self-contained (which [so] aim to be) and perhaps about answering [tag:algorithm] questions with algorithms rather than (just) function names which perform the required functionality (which I think should be standard practice). The higher-voted answer isn't too much better, possibly worse from the self-contained aspect. If you haven't already, you can read [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231), which is about link-only answers, but a lot of what was mentioned in the top answer applies here.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the array and count the number of true values. That is all you need to do. The number of false values is the array_size - #true. This is essentially the same information as the sorted array.

If, for some reason, you need it unpacked (e.g. you need a bitmap for drawing purposes), just memset #false in the array to false, and memset the rest of the array to true (or, vice versa).

Answer (score 0):

From the start, find the first ˋtrueˋ element. From then end, find the first ˋfalseˋ element. Swap them and repeat for remaining elements until both iterators are equals. O(n) for data with 2 states.

For 3 states, I would do someting similar but use extra 2 extra iterators to remember from where I got ˋmaybeˋ.

I am not sure if it would also works with 4 items. It might be greater than O(n) since some items migh be exanged twice!